# User received email about suspicious activity perform from instagram when login from my app into instagram

Tags: ios, cordova, instagram

We have developed an app. When user try to Login through Instagram. They got an email from Instagram about some suspicious activity perform and you need to change your password. Whats the issue with my app. why the get these type of emails ?

When i login into Instagram from my app, i didn't get such type of email. I am from Pakistan. But when my client/users from USA login into Instagram from my app they got this type of email.
Please respond me ASAP, because i have made this app for Coachella festival that will start on coming friday. and before festival start i need to resolve this issue if any.